# QListWidget::addItem gives horrendous flickering

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

This happens when I add items one at a time (adding one item and then returning to the event loop). To illustrate, my code looks roughly like this:

```
    ....................
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(0);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeout()));
    ....................

void Dialog::onTimeout()
{
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem;

    ....................

    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: My OS is Linux (Xubuntu Meerkat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code look OK to me. I ran it on my local machine and it executed without flickering. Are you dealing with intense graphics (even this should be OK due to the way Qt defines timeout(0)... as it waits for event queue to complete)? Most likely there is other code that is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I forgot to mention that I'm using it on Linux (Xubuntu Meerkat to be exact). This flicker might be an OS-specific problem, who knows. Anyway, I'll try to run the code myself in a test project, I hadn't thought to do that.

Comment: That's very strange, even a test project with only this code gives flicker. I was going to give the code, but I don't know how to wrap it in tags (<code></code> or <pre></pre> didn't work).

Comment: in the text edit box (when you edit your question) you can select your text then press the code quickbutton to format it to display as code.